# Trying to find this day last year. Ex: Get the 1st Friday of October, not the October the 4th

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure this is even possible without using PHP, but I'd love to try.

I have a database that looks like this (a bunch of other stuff, but this is all that is relevant:

`Date_Day` (is a range from 1 to 31 with no trailing 0)

`Date_Month` (is a range from January to December, not numerical)

`Date_Year` (is the year in 4 digit format, ex: 2005)

`Total` (number with 2 decimal places)

I know the way the dates are stored is awful, but this is the database I was given. If there is a query that I could use these columns to create an actual DATETIME column, I would happily do it, I just don't know what that query looks like.

I have this query that returns the Total sales amount for this day for all previous years:

```
SELECT 
    Date_Year, Date_Month, SUM(Total) 
FROM 
    tablename 
WHERE 
    Date_Year < YEAR(CURDATE()) 
AND 
    Date_Month = MONTHNAME(CURDATE()) 
AND 
    Date_Day = DAY(CURDATE()) 
GROUP BY 
    Date_Year, Date_Month
```

So if I run this today, I get the daily totals for October 4th for all previous years. The issue is that in sales, this isn't very helpful for comparing growth. What I really need is the daily totals for the 1st Friday in October for all previous years.

Is this possible without having to rely on PHP? If so, I would be very grateful for your help.

Thank you.

Comment: What if you're on, say, the 5th friday of the month? Since the same month won't always have 5 fridays, how should that be dealt with? Should years without a fifth friday be skipped?

Comment: In that case it would be the 1st friday of the following month.

Comment: It's important to think about edge cases like this and put them into your question. I doubt that there's anything built in so you need to give as complete a spec as possible.

Comment: Understood. Thank you. I found this question elsewhere and am wondering if this can be adapted for MySQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215323/how-do-you-find-the-same-weekday-last-year-in-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for **[DAYOFWEEK()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek)**

Returns the weekday index for date (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = Saturday). These index values correspond to the ODBC standard.

```
mysql> SELECT DAYOFWEEK('2007-02-03');
     > 7
```

Comment: That was one of the first results I found when searching how to do this but I'm still lost. I'm looking for a more complete answer. Thank you for your time though, I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    Date_Year, Date_Month, SUM(Total) 
FROM 
    tablename 
WHERE 
    Date_Year < YEAR(CURDATE()) 
AND 
    Date_Month = MONTHNAME(CURDATE()) 
AND 
    Date_Day = DAY(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) - ((28 + WEEKDAY(LAST_DAY(CURDATE())) - 4)))
GROUP BY 
    Date_Year, Date_Month
```

maybe this will help

Comment: This is getting first friday of the month. That is what was needed in question. "What I really need is the daily totals for the 1st Friday in October for all previous years"

Comment: That was just an example. I need this to be able to get this dayofweek last year. Similar to this T-SQL statement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215323/how-do-you-find-the-same-weekday-last-year-in-sql